Currently popped out composable receiving clicks?
I am surprised why dont i find any one in the predicament I am in .
Here is a simple all for you all to test the situation i am in

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            AppNavigator()
        }
    }

@Composable
    fun AppNavigator() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen_a") {
            composable("screen_a") { ScreenA(navController) }
            composable("screen_b") { ScreenB() }
        }
    }
    @Composable
    fun ScreenA(navController: androidx.navigation.NavController) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("screen_b") }) {
                Text("Go to Screen B")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ScreenB() {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().clickable {
                                                        Timber.d("Clicked on B ")
        }, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

            Text("Welcome to Screen B!")

        }
    }

So we open the app ,and see Screen A , we then go to Screen B via the button .
Next we press the system back button and quickly press any region in Screen A , we would see the log "Clicked on B "
I know this is happening because of the Animations perhaps.
However what should be done to keep the animations , while also sort of ignore the clicks on the dying composable? Screen A would completely be blocked for a second or so after the back is pressed which is abysmal.
I am using the following libraries
kotlin = "1.9.23"
compose-compiler = "1.5.11"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.8.0"
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-compose-version = "2.6.2"

Also I have strong skipping enabled .
Please enlighten me guys
UPDATE :
I have seen one solution in which a person suggested that only react to clicks if the current destination is the one we are expecting . This is evil too .
Because in real life application on screen A , if we have a few controls , we would notice that one click that we did immediately when we pressed back on screen B got lost (because B tried to use that click , but we had prevented it from taking action because of current destination mismatch) . So this solution is also a bad hack .
